# jQuery :not with anchor exclude div and img elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I would like to achieve is to style all links on my page which do not contain an image or a div box. I've tried solving this problem with css with `a:text-only` and `a:text-only:hover` but this didn't work. I then tried using jQuery but I can't get the `:not` selector to exclude div boxes and images in an anchor tag.
This is my code so far:

```
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function(){
        var styles = {
            textDecoration: "none",
            padding: "2px",
            WebkitTransition: "0.5s",
            MozTransition: "0.5s",
            OTransition: "0.5s",
            transition: "0.5s"
        };
        $("a").not('div', 'img').css( styles );
    });
</script>
```

and it should exclude links that look like this

```
<a href="index.php"><div class="logo180"></div></a>
```

or this

```
<a href='booklist.php'><img src="images/bookflight.png"></a>
```

Is this possible with jQuery (or css)?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$("a").not(':has(div,img)').css(styles);` **BUT** you need to include only one jQuery version and DIV inside anchor TAG is not valid.

Comment: not() excludes, and an anchor can never be a div or an image

Comment: What is the problem with a div or image in an anchor tag? It works on my page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use [:has()](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) with [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```
$("a").not(':has(div,img)').css( styles );
```

Answer (score 0):

An "a" element is an inline element itself. So just can use this:

```
$("a").css( styles );
```